# Assert.AreEqual(object, object) method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest, assert

How does the `Assert.AreEqual(object, object)` method (in the namespace `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`) determine whether the parameters are equal? Does it make use of the `Object.Equals(object, object)` method (in the `System` namespace)?

Comment: Annoyingly it isn't specified in the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms243413(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find it on that page either. Does that mean there is no where to find out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using [reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1) you can see that it does indeed use Object.Equals.

```
public static void AreEqual<T>(T expected, T actual, string message, params object[] parameters)
{
    if (!object.Equals(expected, actual))
    {
        string str;
        if (((actual != null) && (expected != null)) && !actual.GetType().Equals(expected.GetType()))
        {
            str = (string) FrameworkMessages.AreEqualDifferentTypesFailMsg((message == null) ? string.Empty : ReplaceNulls(message), ReplaceNulls(expected), expected.GetType().FullName, ReplaceNulls(actual), actual.GetType().FullName);
        }
        else
        {
            str = (string) FrameworkMessages.AreEqualFailMsg((message == null) ? string.Empty : ReplaceNulls(message), ReplaceNulls(expected), ReplaceNulls(actual));
        }
        HandleFail("Assert.AreEqual", str, parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the `Assert.AreEqual(object, object)` similar?

Comment: The object, object overload ultimately calls this one.